# DataGridView loses data after failed validation

Tags: datagridview

I have a DataGridView bound to an Access database in a Windows Forms Application. When I create a new row and enter invalid data (validated against the rules set in Access, e.g. cell cannot be empty), then move to a different row, the data is lost. No errors thrown or error information on the DataGridView row.

I've attempted e.cancel on the CellValidating and RowValidating events with no luck.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when system throws exceptions like "NULL value is not allowed in any column where where it is now allowed, Duplicate Primary key etc."

In order to handle and observe this you need to handle "DataError" event of the DataGrid View. There you can use e.Cancel=True which will display the "Error Icon" on the data row that user is working with.

```
Private Sub ctlBrokingIntBrokerageList_DataError(DataGridView As DataGridView, e As DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs) Handles Me.DataError

           If TypeOf (e.Exception) Is FormatException Then
                e.Cancel = True

                If dgvMain.CurrentRow IsNot Nothing Then
                    dgvMain.CurrentRow.ErrorText = e.Message
                End If
            End if 
End sub
```